CI4 - When uploading a file, CI4 creates a folder with the filename and puts the file in the new folder - How not to create dir?
I am trying to upload a file to writeable/fs_upload_data. The file I am trying to upload is, for example, task.sql. It uploads but it somehow create a folder with the same filename and then puts the file in the new dir.  For example, task.sql ends up as writeable/fs_upload_data/task.sql/task.sql. Any file I upload results in a new dir.  Cannot find the bug.  Here is my code:
public function upload_fs_data_file(){
    if($this->request->getMethod() =="post"){
        $file = $this->request->getFile("upload_fs_data_file_name");
        if ($this->request->getMethod() == "post") {
            $validation =  \Config\Services::validation();    
            $rules = [
                "upload_fs_data_file_name" => [
                    "label" => "upload_fs_data_file_name", 
                    "rules" => 
                        'uploaded[upload_fs_data_file_name]'
                ],
            ];
            if ( $this->validate($rules) ){
                $x_file = $this->request->getFile('upload_fs_data_file_name');
                $x_file_name = $x_file->getName();
                print_r($x_file_name);
                $x_file->move(WRITEPATH.'upload_fs_data/'.$x_file_name); 
                // will add redirect once code for uploading works.
            } else {
                // return the validation errors.
                return redirect()->back()
                    ->with('errors', $validation->getErrors())
                    ->with('warning', 'Invalid Data')
                    ->withInput();
            }
        }
    }
}


Eyes must be blurry.
This: $x_file->move(WRITEPATH.'upload_fs_data/'.$x_file_name);
Should be this:  $x_file->move(WRITEPATH.'upload_fs_data/', $x_file_name);
